# Angular multipart/form-data form sending

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, http, post

I'm trying to send data by **Post** request with **"multipart/form-data"** format using AngularJS and I'm really confused because I don't have an idea how to do this.

### How it was

The first solution of my app sended data just by built-in submit method by clicking on `<input type="submit" />` button.

I have follow request: http://yourscr.com/d282cebed47bd55f3315c75bd55189d2.png

You can see that data has a special format. It devided by string 
**-----WebKitFormBoundary....**.

Also the same string there is in Content-type.

### What do I need

After rewriting app with AngularJS I'm trying to send data with exactly same format (because now I can't change anything in backend).
For data sending I use $http service.

```
$http.post( URL , data , {
    headers: {  'Content-Type'  : 'multipart/form-data'}
})
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I have following request:
http://yourscr.com/2e7fd3827d300f4191c96837629adf9f.png

Data have different format, now its just an object.

### Then

I decide try to get data from my Form by using "new FormData()"

```
var fd = new FormData();
$http.post( URL , fd , {
    headers: {  'Content-Type'  : 'multipart/form-data'}
})
```

but it still doesn't work! At this time I have empty data in my request (despite all fields of Form was filled).

Request: http:  //yourscr.com/ab7e05efcba7431eeb73a749936e8d17.png

### Question

Any ideas what I should do to send data with similar format as was using in 1st app solution?

How to send data in 'multipart/form-data' format with AngularJS?

PS

Sorry for links, its about my reputaton. I cant post more than 2 links.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

```
app.config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
});
```

Comment: Unfortunatly doesn't work. What data you put to reqest? Is it just object or FormData() object?

Comment: It's just object. What version of Angular do you use?

Comment: I use last stable version - 1.2.19.